# Storing user generated scopes / segmentation of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd love to hear what people think might be the best practice for this.

I have users which can manage a list of customers. I want them to be able to segment their customers.

For instance a segmentation can be customers who have in the last 5 days purchased an item. Or customers who have not purchased an item at all.

Ideally i'll allow the segmentation to follow several conditions such as:

Customers who have purchased an item in the last 5 days **AND** was registered less than 2 days ago.

How would you go about setting this up and storing it?

I can set columns for each condition, but conditions might have different variations in what scope they use. Furthermore it doesn't work if you want them to be able to set several segments.

Another idea is to use serialization, if so any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: what approach you finally settled for the problem? I'm building a similar module and was looking for different approaches.

Comment: I'd be curious to learn as well